Using VLOOKUP and COUNTIFS to tabulate data in a Google Sheet
Okay, so this is what we are trying to achieve.
Sales person fills out a google form after every telephone call made.  That data then goes into a google sheet as seen below.  Then the managers will get emailed a LookerStudio report every morning with the sales people's call from the previous day.

The issue we are running into is when we try and summarize the data within the "Yesterdays Call Summary" Box
What we would like to see the quantity of calls from the previous day calculated and summarized.  In our example above we would have Answered=2, Left Message=1, Bad Number=1.  (Assuming you are reading this on May 28, 2024)
We have tried combining COUNTIFS and VLOOKUP but with no success.
Any advice?

It would be useful to see the COUNTIFS and VLOOKUP formulas you have tried


You may try this in Cell_L8 for Answered:
=arrayformula(countifs(E:E,K8,int(A:A),today()-1))


try:
=QUERY(QUERY(A:G; 
 "select E,count(G) 
  where todate(A) = date '"&TEXT(L2; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  group by E"); 
 "offset 1"; )

with Total row:
=LET(x; QUERY(QUERY(A:G; 
 "select E,count(G) 
  where todate(A) = date '"&TEXT(L2; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  group by E"); 
 "offset 1"; ); VSTACK(x; HSTACK("Total"; SUM(INDEX(x;;2)))))

